# c++, linux - mmap() permission denied on file created by program, created file has all permissions open

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

The permission keeps being denied, but as far as I can tell, my permissions are *wide* open.

```
//snip
int outfile = creat("outFile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
if (outfile < 0)
{
    cout << "\n" << "output file cannot be opened, error" << "\n";
    cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
    exit(1);
}

int pagesize = getpagesize();
for (int i=0; i<pagesize; i++)
{
    write(outfile, "-", 1);
}

//there is code here that outFile.txt has read and write permissions, and it always says read and write are OK

char* target = (char*)mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, outfile, 0);

if (target == MAP_FAILED)
{
    cout << "\n" << "output mapping did not succeed" << "\n";
    cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    cout << "\n" << "output mapping succeeded" << "\n";
}
//snip
```

This is for a school project, we're given a 1GB file, a 4096 page size, and told we can't just use a write() system call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int outfile = creat("outFile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
```

Two problems here:

1. `creat` creates a file in write-only mode, and it's second parameter is a `mode_t` mask. Passing `O_`flags here, slapped together with `S_` mode bits, results in nonsensical garbage.
2. The parameters to the `mmap` call require a `O_RDWR` file descriptor, and as explained above the `O_RDWR` parameter gets interpreted as a ***file permission bits*** and not a file open mode.

This should be replaced by `open()`, with three parameters:

```
int outfile = open("outFile.txt", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR,
           S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but the instructions state "The output file is to be created from within the pgm using creat." I can't tell if this was deliberate on the part of the professor but it seems unlikely.

Comment: So, create the file using `creat`, write it out, close it, then `open()` it, and `mmap()` it. Bottom line: you cannot `mmap` a file using these `mmap` flags if the file descriptor was created using `creat`, no matter what your professor says.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want execute permission on a text file unless you are generating a script.